# Three.js list of loaded models

Tags: javascript, three.js

In the following code, I try to load a few 3D models using the async `.load`.

```js
async function loadModels(lights, roomWidth, roomHeight) {
    models = []
    const loader = new GLTFLoader(loadingManager);
    loader.load('./models/scifi_light_11.glb', function (gltf) {
        gltf.scene.scale.set(0.02, 0.02, 0.02)
        gltf.scene.rotateZ(-0.7 * Math.PI);
        gltf.scene.receiveShadow = true;
        gltf.scene.castShadow = true;
        //START
        gltf.scene.position.set(-(roomWidth / 2) + 0.32, roomHeight - 0.4, 0);
        scene.add(gltf.scene);
        models.push(gltf);
        //ROOM 2
        const l1 = gltf.scene.clone(true);
        l1.position.set(-roomWidth / 2 + 0.32, roomHeight - 0.4, -roomWidth);
        scene.add(l1);
        models.push(l1);
        //ROOM 3
        const l2 = gltf.scene.clone(true);
        l2.position.set(roomWidth / 2 + 0.32, roomHeight - 0.4, -roomWidth);
        scene.add(l2);
        models.push(l2);
        //ROOM 4
        const l3 = gltf.scene.clone(true);
        l3.position.set(roomWidth / 2 + 0.32, roomHeight - 0.4, -2 * roomWidth);
        scene.add(l3);
        models.push(l3);
        //END
        const l4 = gltf.scene.clone(true);
        l4.position.set(-roomWidth / 2 + 0.32, roomHeight - 0.4, -2 * roomWidth);
        scene.add(l4);
        models.push(l4);
    });
    const loader1 = new GLTFLoader(loadingManager);
    // This work is based on "Sci-Fi Terminal" (https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/sci-fi-terminal-9a9343dd76d848318d09badba8606a63) by Bogdan Kuznetsov (https://sketchfab.com/kuznetsov_bogdan) licensed under CC-BY-4.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/)
    loader1.load('./models/terminal/scene.gltf', function (gltf) {
        let model = gltf.scene;
        model.traverse(function (node) {
            if (node.isMesh) {
                node.castShadow = true;
                // node.receiveShadow = true;
            }
        })
        model.scale.set(8, 8, 8);
        model.rotateY(0.6);
        const randomX = Math.random() * (roomWidth / 4 - (-roomWidth / 4)) + (-roomWidth / 4);
        const randomZ = Math.random() * (roomWidth / 4 - (-roomWidth / 4)) + (-roomWidth / 4);
        model.position.set(randomX, 0, randomZ);
        scene.add(model);
        models.push(model);
    });

    const loader2 = new GLTFLoader(loadingManager);
    // This work is based on "Sci-Fi Capsule" (https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/sci-fi-capsule-25a6c93f3c9148e8931c36421b6a6eb7) by Xavi Pujadas (https://sketchfab.com/XaviPujadas) licensed under CC-BY-NC-ND-4.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/4.0/)
    loader2.load('./models/capsule/scene.gltf', function (gltf) {
        let model = gltf.scene;
        model.traverse(function (node) {
            if (node.isMesh) {
                node.castShadow = true;
                // node.receiveShadow = true;
            }
        });
        model.scale.set(0.01, 0.01, 0.01);
        const randomX = Math.random() * (roomWidth / 4 - (-roomWidth / 4)) + (-roomWidth / 4);
        const randomZ = Math.random() * (roomWidth / 4 - (-roomWidth / 4)) + (-roomWidth / 4);
        model.position.set(randomX, 0, -roomWidth + randomZ);
        model.rotateY(-0.6);
        lights[1].target = model;
        scene.add(model);
        models.push(model);
    });

    const loader3 = new GLTFLoader(loadingManager);
    // This work is based on "Sci-Fi Cube 01" (https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/sci-fi-cube-01-bb70561ab6d44540a55c0752fa5e0857) by Giimann (https://sketchfab.com/giimann) licensed under CC-BY-4.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/)
    loader3.load('./models/cube/scene.gltf', function (gltf) {
        let model = gltf.scene;
        model.traverse(function (node) {
            if (node.isMesh) {
                node.castShadow = true;
                // node.receiveShadow = true;
            }
        });
        model.scale.set(8, 8, 8);
        const randomX = Math.random() * (roomWidth / 4 - (-roomWidth / 4)) + (-roomWidth / 4);
        const randomZ = Math.random() * (roomWidth / 4 - (-roomWidth / 4)) + (-roomWidth / 4);
        model.position.set(roomWidth + randomX, 0.2, -roomWidth + randomZ);
        model.rotateY(0.6);
        lights[2].target = model;
        scene.add(model);
        models.push(model);
    });

    const loader4 = new GLTFLoader(loadingManager);
    // This work is based on "Sci-fi barrel" (https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/sci-fi-barrel-481f7499eaf64b8792bffc59a8b4e05a) by Igor_K. (https://sketchfab.com/Igor_K.) licensed under CC-BY-4.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/)
    loader4.load('./models/barrel/scene.gltf', function (gltf) {
        let model = gltf.scene;
        model.traverse(function (node) {
            if (node.isMesh) {
                node.castShadow = true;
                // node.receiveShadow = true;
            }
        });
        model.scale.set(0.04, 0.04, 0.04);
        const randomX = Math.random() * (roomWidth / 4 - (-roomWidth / 4)) + (-roomWidth / 4);
        const randomZ = Math.random() * (roomWidth / 4 - (-roomWidth / 4)) + (-roomWidth / 4);
        model.position.set(roomWidth + randomX, 0, -2 * roomWidth + randomZ);
        model.rotateY(-0.6);
        lights[3].target = model;
        scene.add(model);
        models.push(model);
    });

    const loader5 = new GLTFLoader(loadingManager);
    // This work is based on "Large Fission/Fusion Hybrid Reactor" (https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/large-fissionfusion-hybrid-reactor-c331666c133042c1a73c438857ce0149) by Lynxon (https://sketchfab.com/lynxon) licensed under CC-BY-4.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/)
    loader5.load('./models/reactor/scene.gltf', function (gltf) {
        let model = gltf.scene;
        model.traverse(function (node) {
            if (node.isMesh) {
                node.castShadow = true;
                // node.receiveShadow = true;
            }
        });
        model.scale.set(0.6, 0.6, 0.6);
        const randomX = Math.random() * (roomWidth / 4 - (-roomWidth / 4)) + (-roomWidth / 4);
        const randomZ = Math.random() * (roomWidth / 4 - (-roomWidth / 4)) + (-roomWidth / 4);
        model.position.set(randomX, 1, -2 * roomWidth + randomZ);
        model.rotateY(-0.6);
        lights[4].target = model;
        scene.add(model);
        models.push(model);
    });

}
```

Obviously, the way I currently add the models to the list **models** is not working.
How do I make this function return a Promise that contains a list of all the loaded models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you want to create a [Promisified](https://javascript.info/promisify#:%7E:text=%E2%80%9CPromisification%E2%80%9D%20is%20a%20long%20word%20for%20a%20simple,callback%20into%20a%20function%20that%20returns%20a%20promise) wrapper around [GLTFLoader.load](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=gltfloader#examples/en/loaders/GLTFLoader.load).

```js
/**
 * Load a GLTF resource in a promisified fashion.
 * @param {string} path A string containing the path/URL of the .gltf or .glb file.
 * @param {THREE.LoadingManager} manager The loading manager to use.  Defaults to THREE.DefaultLoadingManager.
 * @returns {Promise<GLTF>}
 */
function loadGltf(path, manager = THREE.DefaultLoadingManager) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    const loader = new GLTFLoader(manager);
    loader.load(
      path, 
      // Pass the argument of the onComplete callback to resolve
      (gltf) => { resolve(gltf); },
      // Pass null for onProgress, because ES2015 Promises
      // do not natively report progress.
      null,
      // Pass the argument of the onError callback to reject
      (err) => { reject(err); }
    );
  });
}
```

Now, you can instantiate promises for each GLTF.

```js
const p1 = loadGltf( "room1.glb" ).then( 
    /* Do room1 stuff and return the result that you 
       want to appear in the array */ );
const p2 = loadGltf( "room2.glb" ).then( /* ditto */ );
```

Finally, initialize the array and use `Promise.all` to feed it.

```
const models = []
// Notice the spread operator in the push
Promise.all([p1, p2]).then( (gltfs) => models.push( ...gltfs );
```

The `gltfs` parameter in the `then` call will be the results of `p1`, `p2`, etc., in the same order as those promises were passed to `all()`.  You don't have to pass the whole GLTF object out of `p1`, `p2`, etc., however; if each GLTF reduces to one object and its children, for example, you could pass out `gltf.scenes[0].children[0]`.  You just have to be mindful of what you pass out of the promises when you start touching them via the array.

You also need to be mindful of the fact that the array may not be fully initialized by the time the engine reaches your `animate()` call (or any other attempt to access the contents of the array).  That could be dealt with either by wrapping `animate()` in another chained call to `then()`, or else by wrapping any access to the array in a guard like `if(models.length) { ... }`.